# How to add 'public_profile' permission in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

In the Facebook Graph API, other apps automatically add 'public_profile' permission, but business app do not.

I can't find it even in the permission list. How can I add 'public_profile' permission? Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: In what _context_ are you trying to "add" it? Are you implementing FB login yourself, are you using Graph API Explorer to generate tokens, ...?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Graph API Explorer to generate tokens but there is no 'public_profile' permission which I want to add.

Comment: Not sure if that even makes sense, for a business user - do those _have_ a "public profile"? What exactly are you trying to _achieve_?

Comment: I'm trying to post on Instagram using API.

Comment: And where in that process do you need the `public_profile` permission?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've been following YouTube tutorials for posts but found the difference that my task didn't work and unlike the video, I don't have 'public_profile' permission.

Comment: First of all, I would recommend that you follow the official documentation, instead of watching any 3rd-party tutorial videos. _"but found the difference that my task didn't work and unlike the video, I don't have 'public_profile' permission."_ - and what exactly lead you to believe, that this "didn't work" was due to that permission not being granted? Did you get any error message saying something in that regard?

Comment: That permission was automatically added, but hidden in the Graph API Explorer.  And then I resolve the problem through official documentation. Thank you for your recommendation and answers.